# Why is $ d x^{1} \wedge d x^{2} = d x^{1} \otimes d x^{2} - d x^{2} \otimes d x^{1}$ not zero?

Tags: tensor-products

I am learning about tensor products.
In trying to understand the definitions, I seem to be getting
some contradiction.

Consider the differential form

$$
d x^{1} \wedge d x^{2} = d x^{1} \otimes d x^{2} - d x^{2} \otimes d x^{1}.
$$

If I use the symmetry property of the tensor product

$$
d x^{2} \otimes d x^{1} = d x^{1} \otimes d x^{2}
$$

I get 0! This is clearly wrong.
I think that I cannot change places inside the tensor product,
but I cannot justify why.
What is going on?

Comment: What you've written down is commutativity, and as mentioned below, not symmetry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symmetry property of the tensor product is not that $u \otimes v = v \otimes u$: it is that the linear map $S$ satisfying $S(u \otimes v) = v \otimes u$ is invertible (and the inverse has the same form).

That is, on *vector spaces* (or vector bundles or other such things), $S$ is an isomorphism $U \otimes V \cong V \otimes U$, which is how the term "symmetry" applies.

Answer (score 3):

It is *not* true that $dx^1\otimes dx^2=dx^2\otimes dx^1$. You might want to check your book how $dx^1\otimes dx^2$ is *defined*.

Consider a vector space $V$ and $f,g$ being two linear functionals on $V$. Then for $u,v\in V$, one has
$$
(f\otimes g-g\otimes f)(u,v)=f(u)g(v)-g(u)f(v)
$$